# How to insert in a multiple many-to-many table the best way?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a cloth store managing system in C# with SQL Server.

I have more than one many-to-many relationship, which are a relation between Storing Rooms and each kind of clothes(torso Clothes,trousers,shoes,accessories). I don't want to  make 4 many-to-many relationship (this will cost me many other tables because I still have another many to many relationships with these tables, for example: relation between services and items...) so I decided to merge all these in one table.

[image]

The result was that I got too many nulls in that table:

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of these and make my program update the null value if exists and insert a new row just in case all are filled?

here is the source code:(serviceId means the storing room Id, and 'Id' is the Id of the Item being inserted):

```
SqlCommand cmd;
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "St_I_accessoryId":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items VALUES ('" + serviceId + "', '" +
            Id + "',null,null,null)", db);
                break;
            case "St_I_torsoClothId":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items VALUES ('" + serviceId + "', null" +
            ", '" + Id + "',null,null)", db);
                break;
            case "St_I_trouserId":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items VALUES ('" + serviceId + "', null" +
            ",null,null,'" + Id + "'")", db);
                break;
            case "St_I_shoeId":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items VALUES ('" + serviceId + "', null" +
            ",'" + Id + "',null)", db);
                break;
            default:
                //return -1;
                throw new StoringItemException();
        }
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            //this should'nt be reached.
            //return 2;
            throw new StoringItemException();
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your source code related to that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question could be to change your case statement to something like the code below.  Note, I did not test so this code could have typos or bugs.

```
        string sql="";
        case "St_I_accessoryId":
            sql =  string.Format(@"
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items WHERE St_I_serviceid = {0}
            BEGIN
              UPDATE ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items 
              SET ser_I_accessoryId= {1}
              WHERE St_I_serviceid = {0}
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
              INSERT INTO ClothStore.dbo.StoringRooms_Items VALUES ('{0}', '{1}',null,null,null)
            END    
            ",serviceId,Id)
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db);
            break;
```

The reason people are not answering the actual question is because the question itself implies problems with your design and your code.

- It is rare that a RELATIONAL database is improved by reducing the number of relations.  Any concern should be easy to fix -- performance means you have other issue, complexity is easy to solve with views, etc etc.
- You posted code with a typo in it.  This means the code won't compile.
- You describe the "correct" way and then you do something else and wonder why it does not work.

Comment: my code works, but the typos exist because I edited the code before post to get red of some details which are not my concern.

Comment: I described the correct way, but I didn't say that I implemented It, I'am just asking how can do it, in other words how can I insert records in that table without getting too many nulls. Thank You Very Much

Comment: No, the correct way is to have a different table for each relationship not a table that contains multiple relationships.  a table that relates id to accesoryID another table that relates id to pantsID etc. That is the correct way.  If you want to reduce tables you can make that one table but not the way you did.  It would have 3 columns Id, fid, and type.  where type describes which table fid points to.  It is rare this is "better" but it does reduce the number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have many more of such many-to-many relations, than merging into one table might not be the best approach. The number of NULL values in the merged table will increase as you add more relations to this table. The original design you showed with the StoringRoom_Items having relations to the individual item tables would be relatively more optimal. So common columns i.e. applicable to all types of items would reside in this merged table, while the type-specific columns would reside in that type's respective table e.g. Shoes. It is relatively easier to add columns or do other maintenance to each specific-type table without affecting other item types, you reduce the NULL value scenarios and your tables are relatively more normalized.